# 15 Puzzle Program, stuck on up left right down commands

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){

//Function used to set up your game board
   int disp[4][4];
   int i, j;
   int game_over = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for(j = 0;j < 4; j++) {
         printf("Enter a value from 1 - 15 for %d %d: ", i, j);
         scanf("%d", &disp[i][j]);
      }
   }
//Function used to display the game board
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                printf(" _    ");
            else if (disp[i][j] < 10)
                printf(" %d    ",disp[i][j]);  
            else
                printf("%d    ",disp[i][j]);
        }
    } 
// Function to show where cursor is
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                printf("");
        }
    }           
//Skeleton to function to controller
    do{
    char move[10];
    printf("Enter a move: ");
    scanf("%s", move);

    if (strcmp("up", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i >= 1){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i - 1][j];
                    disp[i - 1][j] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp("Up", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i > 1){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i - 1][j];
                    disp[i - 1][j] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp("UP", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i > 1){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i - 1][j];
                    disp[i - 1][j] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }



    else if (strcmp("down", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i < 4){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i + 1][j];
                    disp[i + 1][j] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    else if (strcmp("Down", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i < 4){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i + 1][j];
                    disp[i + 1][j] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp("DOWN", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i < 4){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i + 1][j];
                    disp[i + 1][j] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (strcmp("left", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (j >= 1){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i][j - 1];
                    disp[i][j - 1] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp("Left", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i > 1){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i][j + 1];
                    disp[i][j + 1] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp("LEFT", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i > 1){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i][j + 1];
                    disp[i][j + 1] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (strcmp("right", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (j <= 4){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i][j + 1];
                    disp[i][j + 1] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp("Right", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i > 4){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i][j - 1];
                    disp[i][j - 1] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp("RIGHT", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i > 4){
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i][j - 1];
                    disp[i][j - 1] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Invalid move!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else 
        printf("Invalid Move!");

//Update the board function
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        printf("\n\n");
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                printf(" _    ");
            else if (disp[i][j] < 10)
                printf(" %d    ",disp[i][j]);  
            else
                printf("%d    ",disp[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
    while (game_over == 0);

return 0;
}
```

I am having trouble making the cursor go right or down? I can go left and up, but not the other two. I'm not looking for someone to answer the entire program its just I have been stuck on this for hours and every other code I look at sees similar to mine.[I can get it to correctly do up and left but right and down cause a problem and not sure why.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQoJI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The bug is the checking logic is wrong and the bad practice you followed is lots of repetitive code.

Well I have boiled the code to something simple.

```
    ...
else if (strcmp("down", move) == 0 || strcmp("Down", move) == 0 || strcmp("DOWN", move) == 0){
        int d = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){

        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if (i+1 < 4){  // <--- notice the change
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i + 1][j];
                    disp[i + 1][j] = temp;
                    d = 1;
                    break;     // <-- and this
                }
                else {
                    printf("%s","Invalid move!");
                }
            }
            if( d == 1)
                break;
        }
    }   
    else if (strcmp("right", move) == 0 || strcmp("Right", move) == 0 || strcmp("RIGHT", move) == 0){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){

        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if (disp[i][j] == -1)
                if ( j+1 < 4){    // <--- notice the change
                    int temp = disp[i][j];
                    disp[i][j] = disp[i][j + 1];
                    disp[i][j + 1] = temp;
                    break;        // <-- and this
                }
                else {
                    printf("%s","Invalid move!");
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    ...
```

You can check that there is a `break` statement in case of `down` and `right`. The reason is, when you swap `-1` to the right or down then you will meet up again in the loop iteration.

So without the `break` the result would be

```
_ 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 1 2
3 4 5 6

>>> right

1 2 3 _
4 5 6 7
8 9 1 2
3 4 5 6
```

Another thing is don't repeat code. The readability is worse when you do that. Maintaining the code is even harder. Even better here you can write `swap()` logic and use it. And also the movement of the tiles can also be done with another function.

---

#### Tricky downlogic (Edit-1).

In case of downlogic the simple breaking up the loop wont work because in case you do that there will be a chance that in next iteration it will again get `-1` and try to swap it with next number.

Comment: That makes much more sense, but why wouldn't down work in the edit you showed me?

Comment: @CodeRoad.: Check it now...I have missed a edit I guess.

Comment: I am also trying to make a counter that tell the use how many tiles are out of place, is my logic incorrect? I feel it has to do with the loop, because it gives me a wrong amount. //Function to check if board is correct//function to compare array elements
    int k = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < 4; i++)
    for(j = 0;j < 4; j++)
    if(disp[i][j] != disp_compare[i][j]){
    k++;

Comment: @CodeRoad.; The thing is here..you have asked question. I have answered..this solves the problem you had. Now you face another problem..ask another question. Otherwise this may lead to lots of other questions. That's it.

Comment: I apologize I cant figure out how to format the code in a comment.

Comment: @CodeRoad.: All I can say is you are at right track. You made the counter. Now you check - if it not zero then there is error Otherwise it is matched.

Comment: @CodeRoad.: Take a look at this. You will understand how the site works. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @CodeRoad.: I will later comment on how to do that too or maybe add an edit to the answer...(But when I get time).

Comment: I did find it out, but I changed my thinking and created a new algorithm.